# Launch a node server then, when active, a web browser in systemd (Wayland)

Tags: systemd, d-bus, systemd-unit

I'm developing a web-based application, meant to run in an embedded Linux device. There are two parts I need to have launched when the device boots up: the node server (serving locally) and the [cog web browser](https://github.com/Igalia/cog) pointing to the server url. Since node takes a while to start up and accept connections (about 8 secs), **I need to delay the web browser launch until it's ready**.

I decided to use the systemd [dbus service type](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) for implementing this, the idea is to acquire a dbus name when the node server is fully initialized, so we can launch the web browser as soon as possible. I have made the node server implementation register in dbus with the name `server.node`, then configured the node service this way (server-node.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=starts node backend

[Service]
BusName=server.node
EnvironmentFile=/etc/server/server-node.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/server/main.js 2>&1 | logger
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -2 $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then this is the service for the web browser (browser.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=starts cog web browser
Requires=server-node.service
After=server-node.sevice

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/server/cog.conf
#ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cog http://localhost:3000/ui
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -2 $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

The issue here is **I can't achieve the browser service to wait for the node service to be fully activated**. When I execute `systemctl start server-node.service` the command takes a while (this means systemd is waiting for it to be registered in dbus) and running `systemctl status server-node.service` shows it in `activating` state, after that it goes `active`.

However, if I stop it and run `systemctl start browser.service`, both services are launched, but **the browser is run from the very beginning**, showing an HTTP error because the server is not yet accessible. When I uncomment the `ExecStartPre=` line, so it sleeps for 20 secs before launching the browser, I get everything running properly, but I wouldn't want to use any hardcoded delay.

I have also tried with the `BindsTo=server-node.service` [directive](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BUnit%5D%20Section%20Options), but same happens.

---

***Update***

This is my `main.ts`, where I initialize the server and send an event using the [NestJs event framework](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events):

```
async function bootstrap() {
      // Prepare the environment
      // .........
      await app.listen(port, 'localhost').then(() => {
        if (env === 'DEV') {
          Logger.log(`| ${env} server listening on: http://localhost:${port}  `);
        } else {
          Logger.log(`| ${env} server listening on port ${port}  `);
        }
        // Grab the execution context to emit the app initialized event
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484892/1199132
        app.get(EventEmitter2).emit('app.initialized');
      });
}
bootstrap();
```

Then in `dbus.service.ts` the `app.initialized` event is captured and processed, registering the name in the dbus, using the [dbus-native library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbus-native):

```
@OnEvent('app.initialized', { async: true })
register () {
    Logger.log('Requesting dbus name ' + this.busName, this.constructor.name);
    // Request the bus name
    // See https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-messages
    this.bus.requestName(this.busName, 0, (err, name) => {
        if (err) {
            Logger.error('Error registering dbus name: ' + err, DbusService.name);
        } else {
            Logger.log('Registered dbus name with response: ' + name, DbusService.name);
        }
    });
}
```

**The dbus name is listed** when showing the system dbus names using [`busctl list`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/busctl.html).

Comment: When `server-node.service` starts up to your desired running state, will some file changes happen to trigger `browser.service`, I mean can you use `systemd.path` to do service scheduling

Comment: @山河以无恙 The `server-node.service` launch doesn't imply any modifications in the file system. Definitely I could make it happen, but what I want instead is to have the `browser.service` triggered when the Dbus name gets registered.

Comment: At which point are you taking the bus name in main.js ? that has to be done at the last step right  before you enter your main loop.
We can add delays and service unit hacks until we are blue in the face, it will keep racing anyways ..

Comment: I am also assuming you are DBus.registerService against the system bus .. unless you are running this as an user session.

Comment: @CristianRodríguez I added the code piece where the dbus registration happens. It gets registered in the system bus, I can see it with the `busctl list` command. It seems that systemd properly sets it up as a dbus service (as I said in the question, running `systemctl start server-node` from the shell takes a while) but it seems that the orchestration with the browser service fails.

Comment: is there any event when it is ready to start accepting requests ? or is there a callback that may be executed when ready to serve requests ?

Comment: The callback in `app.listen` gets invoked when the server is ready to listen requests. This emits a `app.initialized` event, which triggers the listener that registers the name in dbus, using `this.bus.requestName`. Until this point, the `server-node` service remains in `activating` state (`systemctl status server-node`), which is okey, but the `browser` service has already been started, which is not okey!!

Comment: having a server listening is not the same thing as it been ready to serve requests..isn't ready signaled any other way ?
Other than
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/server/main.js 2>&1 | logger
not needing redirection and pipe to logger (because systemd captures the error log in the journal) and that both services most likely need to want and after network.target I do not see any error on your unit files.

Comment: Why aren't you using `type=dbus` in node-server.service?

Comment: @Marcel, from the [systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), on dbus type: `This type is the default if BusName= is specified. `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need, below:

[DBus services](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

For services that acquire a name on the DBus system bus, use Type=dbus and set BusName= accordingly. The service should not fork (daemonize). systemd will consider the service to be initialized once the name has been acquired on the system bus. The following example shows a typical DBus service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple DBus service

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.example.simple-dbus-service
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/simple-dbus-service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For bus-activatable services, do not include a [Install] section in the systemd service file, but use the SystemdService= option in the corresponding DBus service file, for example (/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.example.simple-dbus-service.service):

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.example.simple-dbus-service
Exec=/usr/sbin/simple-dbus-service
User=root
SystemdService=simple-dbus-service.service
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't make it work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/server/main.js 2>&1 | logger

You can't use shell syntax here, eg. the `2>&1 | logger` part is not allowed.
*(It's actually not needed either as the stdout and stderr are captured and viewable using `systemctl status` and/or `journalctl` anyhow...)*

> The issue here is I can't achieve the browser service to wait for the node service to be fully activated.

For that i suggest you to create a "semaphore file" when it is ready to accept connections, lets say `/tmp/node.server.ready` (Just an empty regular file).
Then create a `*.path` unit that starts the browser unit, using the `Unit=browser.service` directive, when the file is created using the `PathExists=/tmp/node.server.ready` directive.
See: `man systemd.path`

- ⚠️Make sure to remove the `/tmp/node.server.ready` file before starting the node server, and again when the node server is stopped...

That way you should **ONLY enable** the `server-node.service` and make that pull-in the path unit, which in turn will activate the `browser.service` when it's properly ready...